# Create expression tree on parent object from existing expression for c# mongodb driver parsing

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees, mongodb-.net-driver, expressionvisitor

I have a class like this :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

And I have an other generic class like :

```
public class MyParentObject<T>
{

    public T Item { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

I have for example an expression like this :

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expression = p => p.Name == "MyName" && p.Email = "example@test.com"
```

How can I transform this expression to :

```
Expression<Func<MyParentObject<Person>, bool>> expression = p => p.Item.Name == "MyName" && p.Item.Email = "example@test.com"
```

EDIT :

I think my question wasn't enough develop, I would like a method like this :

```
public static Expression<Func<MyParentObject<T>, bool>> GetParentExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    Expression <Func<MyParentObject<T>, bool>> result = // process...
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

EDIT :

I must create a new tree expression which will be parsed then by c# mongodb driver. I can't use Invoke an other Compile methods on expression tree.

I think I must use [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't know how...

Comment: I belive the expression conversion is correct, you have an error in p.Item.Email = "example@test.com", it should be p.Item.Email == "example@test.com", else post the error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Expression.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170(v=vs.110).aspx) for that like this

```
public static Expression<Func<MyParentObject<T>, bool>> GetParentExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    Expression<Func<MyParentObject<T>, T>> item = parent => parent.Item;
    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyParentObject<T>, bool>>(
        Expression.Invoke(expression, item.Body), item.Parameters);
    return result;
}
```

**Update:** Another way which requires a bit more code, but eliminates the `Expression.Invoke` is to use a [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) derived class to replace the parameter of the passed expression like this

```
public static Expression<Func<MyParentObject<T>, bool>> GetParentExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    Expression<Func<MyParentObject<T>, T>> item = parent => parent.Item;
    var body = new ParameterExpressionReplacer { source = expression.Parameters[0], target = item.Body }.Visit(expression.Body);
    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyParentObject<T>, bool>>(body, item.Parameters);
    return result;
}

class ParameterExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression source;
    public Expression target;
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == source ? target : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i can't use Expression.Invoke because my expression is then use by c# mongodb driver which parse expression tree to tranform it on mongo query

Comment: Then you have to change the question. My answer is perfectly covering it the way it is now.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your edit. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much